# Using DocuSign API to extract signers' information from Word doc and transfer them to DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

To streamline the use of DocuSign by a sender, I have created templates that use IDR and autoplace so that fields are placed wherever signature boxes are present on a Word document.

However, it is still time-consuming to manually enter the signers in the correct order on DocuSign. If the name and job titles of the signers are already on the Word document, is there a way to extract that information and transfer it to DocuSign (perhaps using DocuSign API) so that the information wouldn't need to be entered manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the sender is entering recipient/signer information into a Word document, then the Word doc is sent for signing via DocuSign. Goal: you'd like to automatically pull the recipient information out of the Word doc and into DocuSign. Yes?

The issue in this scenario is to maintain the recipient information in a semantic format where you know which data is the name/email of signer 1, signer 2, etc.

That can be difficult in Word unless you add a form to the Word document. If you're willing to add a form to the Word doc, then you'd later use the Word API to pull the data out of Word and add it to DocuSign.

I think an easier answer would be to build a web application where the signers' information is added to a web form. The application would then use that information to both create the Word (or PDF) document and then send it using the DocuSign API.